# object / shape / piece fitting

Tags: c

I've been thinking for a few days about the best solution for this but can't seem to get the right idea on how to do this.

I have a pieces (objects) and I want to fit them in the smallest possible space.
What I'm ultimately looking for is something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg09E.gif

But a simpler version of just calculating the best possible fit of two lines(stripes) would already do for now
like the lines(stripes) on the right

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HijMo.jpg

What I have is 2 arrays of points(vertices) on a xy axis representing two lines(stripes) and I'd like to arrange them in such a manner that  there is  10 or 20 mm space between the closest point of the  two.

I was thinking of looking at the first half of the array and finding the highest point then looking at the second half and finding it's highest point  then compare the two
but that doesn't really seem to be a proper solution.

And I can't really imagine writing a program that fits shapes as in the first image is even possible using such methods.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Generally, this is a hard (NP) problem. There isn't an easy and fast solution that works in every case. Still, you might find reasonable simplifications and heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is really possible.

All you would Have to do is build area and distance function. You might need to add different algorithms for different kinds of shapes.

For the Ones you have provided in the first picture, it is difficult to calculate area. So, Probably will have to specify distance of vertices. Also, you need to add a condition to make sure that the locus of the shapes does not co-incide at any point.

Comment: Not quite an answer, I think.